# Python Parsing Expect Script Output

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, expect, flags

I have a large Expect script output file containing a list of devices and their TACACS server IP addresses.

I wanted to iterate through that file and, for each device, determine if its got: only the new TACACS IP addresses; or the new and the old; or, neither. (old only is out of the question as i added the new to all devices; but, would be nice to include for future requirements...)

For "security" I replaced the actual device names and IP addresses with dummy data. Also, the "print" statements which replaced the "write" statements are just leftovers from troubleshooting.

```
Here is the script:

 #!/usr/bin/python

 import re

#####################################################

new1 = "tacacs-server host 1.1.1.1"
new2 = "tacacs-server host 2.2.2.2"
new1_in_block = 0
new2_in_block = 0
```

has_new_ip = 0

```
#####################################################
  old1 = "tacacs-server host 2.2.2.2" 
  old2 = "tacacs-server host 3.3.3.3" 
  old3 = "tacacs-server host 4.4.4.4"
  old4 = "tacacs-server host 5.5.5.5"
  old5 = "tacacs-server host 6.6.6.6"
  old6 = "tacacs-server host 7.7.7.7"

 has_old_ip = 0
```

#

```
 tacacs_servers = open ("test_block3.txt","r+")
```

#

```
complete =  open  ("complete_output.txt","r+")
```

#

```
 not_complete =  open  ("not_complete_output.txt","r+")

######################################################

not_checked = open ("not_checked.txt","r+")

#####################################################

 for line in tacacs_servers:

 if 'show' in line:
  DeviceName = (re.search(".*#",line).group())
  DeviceName = DeviceName.replace('#',' ')

 if 'show' not in line:

  if str(new1) or str(new2) in line:
   has_new_ip = 1

  elif str(new1) or str(new2) not in line:
   has_new_ip = 0

 if 'spawn' in line:
  if has_new_ip == 0:
   print (DeviceName)
   print ("NOT COMPLETE\n")

  elif has_new_ip == 1:
   print (DeviceName)
   print ("COMPLETE\n")


 new1= new2 = has_new_ip = 0
 old1 = old2 = old3 = old4 = old5 = old6 = has_old_ip = 0

    Here is test_block3.txt:


    ABC-DEF#show run | include tacacs-server host
    tacacs-server host 1.1.1.1
    GHI-JKL#spawn ssh -q user@MN-OPQ


    MN-OPQ#show run | include tacacs-server host
    tacacs-server host 1.1.1.1
    tacacs-server host 3.3.3.3
    tacacs-server host 2.2.2.2
    MN-OPQ# #spawn ssh -q user@AZXY-123

    AZXY-123# show run | include tacacs-server host
    AZXY-123# spawn ssh -q  user@P44AR-1212



  Here is the current Python Script output:

  ABC-DEF 
  COMPLETE

  MN-OPQ 
  COMPLETE

  AZXY-123 
  COMPLETE
```

Comment: Do you really mean `if str(new1) or str(new2) in line`?  I think you probably want `if new1 in line or new2 in line`.  The first expression will always evaluate to new1 which is not the empty string, so that `has_new_ip` will always be set to 1.  Since new1 and new2 are strings to begin with, there's no reason to use `str(new1)` and `str(new2`)`

Comment: Thank you for asking; I meant it as I wrote it; when I left out str(), the interpreter wouldn't take it; it printed some error about an "int" before "in line" when a string was required.

Comment: What am I overlooking?  `>>> new1 = "tacacs-server host 1.1.1.1"
>>> str(new1) == new1
True
>>> if str(new1) or 2 == 3: print('Yes')
... 
Yes`  I don't know how to format this in a comment.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sure not most elegant way but:

```
import re

f=open('list.txt','r')

devices_list={}
device_name=None

old_ip_list=['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2']
new_ip_list=['3.3.3.3']

for line in f:
    match=re.search('^(.*)\s*#\s*show\s+run',line)
    if match!=None:
        device_name=match.groups()[0].strip()
        devices_list[device_name]=[]
        continue
    match=re.search('tacacs-server\s+host\s+(\S+)',line)
    if match!=None:
        host=match.groups()[0].strip()
        devices_list[device_name].append(host)


print devices_list

devices_list_new={}
new_list=[]
old_list=[]
both_list=[]
neither_list=[]

for device in devices_list.keys():
    devices_list_new[device]=[]
    for ip in devices_list[device]:
        if ip in old_ip_list:
            devices_list_new[device].append('old')
        elif ip in new_ip_list:
            devices_list_new[device].append('new')


for device in devices_list_new.keys():
    if 'old' in devices_list_new[device] and 'new' in devices_list_new[device]:
        both_list.append(device)
    elif 'new' in devices_list_new[device]:
        new_list.append(device)
    elif 'old' in devices_list_new[device]:
        old_list.append(device)
    else:
        neither_list.append(device)

print 'New:'
for device in new_list:
    print device

print 'Old:'
for device in old_list:
    print device

print 'Both:'
for device in both_list:
    print device

print 'Neither:'
for device in neither_list:
    print device
```